# CUDA Thrust Device strcmp

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have made the following code to be able to be used to sort an array of char * using THRUST sort method. For some reason the code is  breaking whenever it tries to compare the chars in the string.

```
thrust::sort_by_key(deviceArrayToSort.begin(),deviceArrayToSort.end(),deviceArrayToSortRow.begin(),CharArrayCmp());
```

The comparator is below:

```
struct CharArrayCmp{
__host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const CharArr & o1, const CharArr & o2) {
      return this->compare(o1.value,o1.length,o2.value,o2.length);
  }

    __host__ __device__ bool compare (const char * src, int lenSrc, const char * dst, int lenDest)
{
    int end;
    if(lenSrc > lenDest){
        end = lenDest;
    }else{
        end = lenSrc;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < end; i++){
        if(src[i] > dst[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(lenSrc >= lenDest){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

};

When it tries to run on the device on this line there is an error:

```
if(src[i] != dst[i])

    thrust::system::cuda::detail::detail::launch_closure_by_value<thrust::system::cuda::detail::
detail::stable_sort_by_count_detail::stable_sort_by_count_closure<256u, 
thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::pointer<unsigned int, 
thrust::system::cuda::detail::tag, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default> >, 
thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::pointer<unsigned int, 
thrust::system::cuda::detail::tag, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default> >, 
    thrust::system::cuda::detail::temporary_indirect_ordering<thrust::system::cuda::detail::tag,
 thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<CharArr> >, CharArrayCmp>::compare, 
thrust::system::cuda::detail::detail::statically_blocked_thread_array<256u> > > [0] [device 
0 (GK104)]  (Signal) - CUDA_EXCEPTION_10:Device Illegal Address 

CUDA Thread (193,0,0) Block (22,0,0)    


All Kernel Threads (144 Blocks of 256 Threads)
```

I am quite new to CUDA so I am uncertain of what I am doing wrong but it feels like this should be pretty straightforward.

This is the CharArr struct:

```
typedef struct{

char * value;
int length;
} CharArr;
```

And finally here is the code that makes use of this sort_by_key. I have made sure that the information being passed into this is correct. Namely that arrayToSort and arrayToSortRow are both arrays, of char * and long long respectively and size is the size of these two arrays.

```
void sortCharArrayStable(char ** arrayToSort, long long * arrayToSortRow,long long size){
std::cout <<"about to start LongIndex" <<std::endl;

        thrust::host_vector<CharArr> hostToSort(size);
        thrust::host_vector<long long> hostToSortRow(size);
        for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
            CharArr sortRow;
            if(arrayToSort[i] == 0x0){
                sortRow.length = 0;
                sortRow.value = "";
                std::cout<<"Had an error on row "<< arrayToSortRow[i]<<" when making column array for sortCharArrayStable"<<std::endl;

            }else{

                sortRow.length = strlen(arrayToSort[i]);
                sortRow.value = arrayToSort[i];
            }



            hostToSort[i] = sortRow;
            hostToSortRow[i] = arrayToSortRow[i];
        }
        thrust::device_vector<CharArr> deviceArrayToSort = hostToSort;// (arrayToSort,arrayToSort + size);
        thrust::device_vector<long long> deviceArrayToSortRow = hostToSortRow;




thrust::stable_sort_by_key(deviceArrayToSort.begin(),deviceArrayToSort.end(),deviceArrayToSortRow.begin(),CharArrayCmp());

        //copy the contents back into our original array to sort now sorted
        hostToSort = deviceArrayToSort;
        for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
            arrayToSort[i] = hostToSort[i].value;
        }
        arrayToSortRow);


thrust::copy(deviceArrayToSortRow.begin(),deviceArrayToSortRow.end(),arrayToSortRow);


}
```

Here is a complete example of the issue ocurring in a compilable example:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>

#include <thrust/reduce.h>


typedef struct{

    char * value;
    int length;
} CharArr;


struct CharArrayCmp{
    __host__ __device__
      bool operator()(const CharArr & o1, const CharArr & o2) {
          return this->compare(o1.value,o1.length,o2.value,o2.length);
      }

    __host__ __device__ bool compare (const char * src, int lenSrc, const char * dst, int lenDest)
    {
        int end;
        if(lenSrc > lenDest){
            end = lenDest;
        }else{
            end = lenSrc;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < end; i++){
            if(src[i] > dst[i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(lenSrc >= lenDest){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};


void sortCharArray(char ** arrayToSort, long long * arrayToSortRow,long long size){
    std::cout <<"about to start LongIndex" <<std::endl;

            thrust::host_vector<CharArr> hostToSort(size);
            thrust::host_vector<long long> hostToSortRow(size);
            for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
                CharArr sortRow;
                sortRow.value = arrayToSort[i];
                sortRow.length = strlen(arrayToSort[i]);
                hostToSort[i] = sortRow;
                hostToSortRow[i] = arrayToSortRow[i];
            }
            thrust::device_vector<CharArr> deviceArrayToSort = hostToSort;// (arrayToSort,arrayToSort + size);
            thrust::device_vector<long long> deviceArrayToSortRow = hostToSortRow;//(arrayToSortRow,arrayToSortRow + size);

           // thrust::sort(deviceArrayToSort.begin(),deviceArrayToSort.end());
            thrust::sort_by_key(deviceArrayToSort.begin(),deviceArrayToSort.end(),deviceArrayToSortRow.begin(),CharArrayCmp());

            //copy the contents back into our original array to sort now sorted
            hostToSort = deviceArrayToSort;
            for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
                arrayToSort[i] = hostToSort[i].value;
            }
            thrust::copy(deviceArrayToSortRow.begin(),deviceArrayToSortRow.end(),arrayToSortRow);


}

int main()
{
    char ** charArr = new char*[10];

    charArr[0] = "zyxw";
    charArr[1] = "abcd";
    charArr[2] = "defg";
    charArr[3] = "werd";
    charArr[4] = "aasd";
    charArr[5] = "zwedew";
    charArr[6] = "asde";
    charArr[7] = "rurt";
    charArr[8] = "ntddwe";
    charArr[9] = "erbfde";

    long long * rows = new long long[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++ ){
        rows[i] = i;
    }

    sortCharArray(charArr,rows,10);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        std::cout<<"Row is "<<rows[i]<<" String is "<<charArr[i]<<std::endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?  Sort an array of character strings? (In that case it's not clear to me why you are using "sort_by_key" instead of just "sort") The comparator that you pass to sort is intended to be an *ordering* comparator.  It does not appear that your comparator is doing that - it is testing for string "equality".

Comment: Hey Robert I am sorting an array of char * (c strings). CharArr is a struct with two values. One being the value (a char *) and the other being the length (the number of chars in the char *). I needed this since I did not have strlen to see the length of the char * when doing comparisons. As for the ordering comparator, its a weak ordering comparator (thats what thrust is expecting). The error is happening on the line I mention though ( if(src[i] != dst[i]) )

Comment: Probably you should show the definition of your `CharArr` struct as well.  Your comparator cannot be used to order two strings.  You should study this to understand it.  Suppose I have two strings of unequal length that I pass to the comparator.  The comparator will return "false" regardless of the order in which I pass the strings.  Therefore it cannot be an ordering comparator.  Likewise if I have two strings of equal length whose first character differs, the comparator will return false regardless of the order in which I present the strings.  It cannot be an ordering comparator.

Comment: I have done that though I should be clear the main issue seems to be occurring when I try to access a character from a char *. Also you are correct it is not correctly ordering I will have to fix that in the code thank you for noticing. But the main issue I am having is actually accessing the values of the char in the char *

Comment: I also fixed the comparator. Thank you for noticing I was thinking in terms of how I make my comparators in java :).

Comment: It's likely that the pointers in your `CharArr` objects are not initialized properly.  However it's impossible to tell this from the code you have posted.  You should probably post a short, complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem.  Are you setting up a host_vector of these `CharArr` objects and then copying that to a device vector?  That will not copy the strings that are pointed to in that case, and the pointers in the device_vector will be invalid (when dereferenced in device code).

Comment: Hey I am testing that out Now I will make a compilable example to test and post it here later.

Comment: I just added that. Also not sure if these means anything but when I try to look at the values of these char * i see the following <optimized_out>

Comment: Actually what you just added is still a snippet of code.  Why not make it easy on those who are trying to help you by posting a *complete*, *compilable* code?  Something that I can copy, paste, compile, without adding anything or changing anything, and then run it to demonstrate the problem.  Otherwise I have to probably create a bunch of stuff myself.  It seems to me like you are asking for the help, you should do this work.

Comment: So I have checked the CharArr are initialized properly. Theres no error in what is contained on the Host side. The only issue I am seeing is trying to access the actual char * on the device.

Comment: Good point Robert. I have to admit I have never asked questions on a forum before (I am kind of a lone ranger) I will make a compilable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work:

```
    thrust::device_vector<CharArr> deviceArrayToSort = hostToSort;// (arrayToSort,arrayToSort + size);
    thrust::device_vector<long long> deviceArrayToSortRow = hostToSortRow;

    thrust::stable_sort_by_key(deviceArrayToSort.begin(),deviceArrayToSort.end(),deviceArrayToSortRow.begin(),CharArrayCmp());
```

Each `CharArr` object in `hostToSort` contained a pointer that points to a host memory location.  The numerical value of this pointer is *unchanged* when you copy it to a device vector.  If you then try and dereference this (bogus) pointer in device code, it will fail exactly as you are seeing.

You will need to go through the `deviceArrayToSort` device vector, and for each `CharArr` object in it, you will need to adjust its `value` pointer to point to a valid location in device memory, which would presumably be the starting address of each character string to sort.

Comment: Wow that makes complete and total sense thank you for all your help. you are awesome